# Randomly place 1D string array into 2D char array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to randomly place 1D string array into 2D char array but I'm having issues with my for-loop. 
userWords is 1D array of String while puzzleBoard is a 2D array of char.

I've tried

```
for(int i=0; i<userWords.length;i++) {
        puzzleBoard[r++] = userWords[i].toCharArray(); 
    }
```

[but it's not placing it randomly like I want it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coNon.png)

So I tried

```
    for(int i=0; i<userWords.length;i++) {
        int r = rand.nextInt(ROW) + 1;
        int c = rand.nextInt(COLUMN) + 1;
        puzzleBoard[r][c] = userWords[i].charAt(i);
    }
```

but it's printing only 3 char instead of the 3 strings of char into the char array.

I've also tried

```
    puzzleBoard[r][c] = userWords[i].toCharArray();
```

instead of

```
    puzzleBoard[r][c] = userWords[i].charAt(i);
```

But it display error "cannot convert from char[] to char"

Thank you

**Full Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] userWords = new String[3];
    Methods.userInput(userWords); //ask user for input 
    Methods.fillPuzzle(puzzleBoard); //fill the puzzle with random char

    for(int i=0; i<userWords.length;i++) {
        int r = rand.nextInt(ROW) + 1;
        int c = rand.nextInt(COLUMN) + 1;
        puzzleBoard[r][c] = userWords[i].charAt(i);
    }

    Methods.printPuzzle(puzzleBoard); //print out the puzzle

}//end main 


public static void printPuzzle(char a[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print((i+1));
        System.out.println();
    }

}//end printPuzzle

public static void fillPuzzle(char a[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}//end fillPuzzle

public static void userInput(String a[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1) + ". enter word:");
        a[i] = input.next().toUpperCase();
    }
}//end userInput
```

Comment: Can you give full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < userWords.length; i++) {
     int r = rand.nextInt(puzzleBoard.length);
     int c = rand.nextInt(puzzleBoard[r].length - userWords[i].length());
     for (int j = 0; j < userWords[i].length(); j++) {
        puzzleBoard[r][c + j] = userWords[i].charAt(j);
     }
  }
```

And you should add something that detects whether there is already a word at this position, otherwise you would overwrite it if the random numbers point to a location where is already written a word.

Comment: It works! I was having such a hard time, thank you. And yes I'm planning to do that right after

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use 2 for-loops because you want to select first the string and next the characters in the string.

```
    for(int i=0; i<userWords.length;i++) {
       int r = rand.nextInt(ROW) + 1;
       int c = rand.nextInt(COLUMN) + 1;
       for (int j = 0; j < userWords[i].length(); j++) {
          puzzleBoard[r][c + j] = userWords[i].charAt(j);
       }
    }
```